# Mate Panel gap between main menu and window list

Tags: panel, mate

I have a gap between the main menu and window list on Mate Panel, is there a way to remove the gap?

[image: Very cropped screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right-click anywhere on the panel and select **Properties** from the context menu

[image]

In the dialog box uncheck **Expand**

[image]

The panel will compress to the centre, removing the gaps